# Wordpress CF7 reloads page after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

After submit mail sends, but page reloads, and cf7 adds form id to url as hash.

I find this [article](https://contactform7.com/why-isnt-my-ajax-contact-form-working-correctly/), where possible reasons displayed. But I have no errors in console, validator doesn't find any problems and wp_head(), wp_footer() are in the right place. Maybe you can suggest some other way out of this problem?

Comment: Change theme to twentytwenty three for example and test.